# How can I sort a table by ascending numbers from a specified column in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, html-table

I have a table that get data from an object called *blockInfo*:

```
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Timestamp</th>
                        <th>Block #</th>
                        <th>Block Hash</th>
                        <th>Miner</th>
                        <th>Gas used</th>
                        <th>Txs #</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {blockInfo.map((block) =>
                        < tr >
                            <td >{timeSince(new Date(block.timestamp * 1000))}</td>
                            <td id="blockNumber">{block.number}</td>
                            <td id="blockHash" >{block.hash}</td>
                            <td>{block.miner}</td>
                            <td>{block.gasUsed}</td>
                            <td>{block.transactions.length}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

It produces that table:
[image: image of the table]

I want to sort that table by ascending numbers from **Block #** column, I tried adding **`.sort()`** in this way but it didn't work:

```
                <tbody>
                    {blockInfo.sort((a, b) => {
                        if (a > b) return 1;
                        if (a < b) return -10;
                        return 0;
                    }).map((block) =>
                        < tr >
                            <td >{timeSince(new Date(block.timestamp * 1000))}</td>
                            <td id="blockNumber">{block.number}</td>
                            <td id="blockHash" >{block.hash}</td>
                            <td>{block.miner}</td>
                            <td>{block.gasUsed}</td>
                            <td>{block.transactions.length}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
```

Does anyone how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the mistake lies in your sorting function. The arguments `a` and `b` each represent an object in the `blockInfo` list. Therefore, for the sorting function to work properly, you need to specify the key on which you wish to sort.

Try this code:

```
<tbody>
         {blockInfo.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.number > b.number) return 1; // .number is added 
                if (a.number < b.number) return -10; // .number is added
                return 0;
             }).map((block) =>
                        < tr >
                            <td >{timeSince(new Date(block.timestamp * 1000))}</td>
                            <td id="blockNumber">{block.number}</td>
                            <td id="blockHash" >{block.hash}</td>
                            <td>{block.miner}</td>
                            <td>{block.gasUsed}</td>
                            <td>{block.transactions.length}</td>
                        </tr>
             )}
</tbody>
```